# How to get SonarCube project unit test converge per user?

Tags: sonarqube

Is there an API to get the SonarCube project, unit test converge per user, if not can we derive the user-wise coverage from other API responses?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused about what test coverage means.  It measures the number of lines in your business logic that is "covered" by automated unit tests.  It's not something that is measured at runtime, nor does it have anything to do with "users".

Comment: Is it possible to calculate user test coverage by (covered code lines)/(total code lines by user) ?

Comment: What association exists for a "user"?  Are you trying to associate lines of code with the userid that last changed that line?  This is a pointless association.

Comment: yes, that was the requirement, is there any way to achieve this, direct or indirect?